# SSL сертификат и Webpack-dev-server

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, openssl, webpack-dev-server

Я разрабатываю приложение с использованием WebPack
Сейчас мне потребовалось использовать в разработке https протокол.

Установил openssl 
Создал сертификат с Subject Alternative Names
Установил сертификат в windows

https://localhost/ открывается.

Но devServer использует порт 9000
стоит переопределение http to https

и когда я хочу на локальной машине открыть проект

по ссылке https://localhost:9000/ 
выдаёт
если

```
devServer: {
contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
compress: true,
host: 'localhost',
port: 9000,
publicPath: '/static/',
https: false,
key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt'),
ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca.pem')
}
```

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Если я на сервере включаю 
передачу данных по https

```
devServer: {
contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
compress: true,
host: 'localhost',
port: 9000,
publicPath: '/static/',
https: true,
key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt'),
ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca.pem')
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку

NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

```
Subject: localhost

Issuer: xxxx

Expires on: 22 авг. 2028 г.

Current date: 25 авг. 2018 г.

PEM encoded chain:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

В чём может быть проблема ?
Или как сделать что бы сертификат распространялся на порт 9000 ?

Comment: «ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID» — да, самопальные сертификаты всегда будут невалидные, так и задумано в SSL

Comment: Да почему, сделал, работает.
Конечно, это исключительно для разработки.

Answer (score 0):

1. Самый простой способ сделать сертификат.

(это для windows)

[How to set up IIS with SSL (HTTPS) on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTlc5Z59FpA)

2. Но по инструкциям видео ошибка осталась. Зашёл в настройки Chrome и там ещё установил сертификат.

   ```
   devServer: { 
   contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), 
   compress: true, 
   port: 9000, 
   publicPath: '/static/', 
   pfx: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/localhost.pfx'), 
   pfxPassphrase: 'passphrase', 
   https: true 
   // key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.key'), 
   // cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt'), 
   // ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/rootCA.pem') 
   }

   "scripts": { 
   "dev": "webpack-dev-server —mode development —open —hot —pfx-passphrase "passphrase", 
    "build": "node build.js" 
   },
   ```
3. Service Worker работает